# PHP how to make some selectbox from a database query

Tags: php, mysql, database, drop-down-menu

i wanna get this, value of 3 selectbox are same:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/EqvpT.jpg

then, i write this code:

```
$jabatan = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM jabatan WHERE id_jabatan NOT IN (1,10,11,12)") or die(mysql_error());

if (isset($_GET['id'])) {

$query = mysql_query("SELECT *, month(tanggal_larut) as bulan_larut, day(tanggal_larut) as hari_larut, year(tanggal_larut) as tahun_larut FROM larut WHERE id_larut ='$_GET[id]'") or die(mysql_error());

$row = mysql_fetch_object($query);
}

<li>
    <label>Pemateri 1</label>
    <select name="pemateri1">
            <?php
            while ($p1 = mysql_fetch_object($jabatan)) {
            ?>
            <option value="<?php echo isset($p1->id_jabatan) ? $p1->id_jabatan : '' ?>" <?php if (isset($_GET['id'])) { if($p1->id_jabatan == $row->pemateri1) {echo "selected";} else {echo "";} }  ?> ><?php echo isset($p1->nama_jabatan) ? $p1->nama_jabatan : '' ?></option>
            <?php
            }
            ?>
    </select>
</li>
<li>
    <label>Pemateri 2</label>
    <select name="pemateri2">
            <?php
            while ($p2 = mysql_fetch_object($jabatan)) {
            ?>
            <option value="<?php echo isset($p2->id_jabatan) ? $p2->id_jabatan : '' ?>" <?php if (isset($_GET['id'])) { if($p2->id_jabatan == $row->pemateri2) {echo "selected";} else {echo "";} }  ?> ><?php echo isset($p2->nama_jabatan) ? $p2->nama_jabatan : '' ?></option>
            <?php
            }
            ?>
    </select>
</li>
<li>
    <label>Pemateri 3</label>
    <select name="pemateri3">
            <?php
            while ($p3 = mysql_fetch_object($jabatan)) {
            ?>
            <option value="<?php echo isset($p3->id_jabatan) ? $p3->id_jabatan : '' ?>" <?php if (isset($_GET['id'])) { if($p3->id_jabatan == $row->pemateri3) {echo "selected";} else {echo "";} }  ?> ><?php echo isset($p3->nama_jabatan) ? $p3->nama_jabatan : '' ?></option>
            <?php
            }
            ?>
    </select>
</li>
```

i get this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/vYnpd.jpg

Ok, please somebody help me, how to correct the code? thanks

Comment: Please format your code

Comment: sorry this is my first time, fixed.

Comment: issue solved or in pending?

Comment: @Zeeshan pending.... can you help me?

Comment: your code is susceptible to SQL injection. Please use PDO or mysqli parameterized query. Also mysql is deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this.... if you want the same select box option why using more time while loop, you can do in one loop. For sql injection read this [REF](https://www.acunetix.com/websitesecurity/sql-injection/)

```
<?php
$jabatan = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM jabatan WHERE id_jabatan NOT 
IN (1,10,11,12)") or die(mysql_error());

if (isset($_GET['id'])) {

    $query = mysql_query("SELECT *, month(tanggal_larut) as bulan_larut,
    day(tanggal_larut) as hari_larut, year(tanggal_larut) as tahun_larut
    FROM larut WHERE id_larut ='".mysql_real_escape_string($_GET[id])."'") or
    die(mysql_error());

    $row = mysql_fetch_object($query);
}

$Selectbox_options = '';
while ($p1 = mysql_fetch_object($jabatan)) {
    $value = isset($p1->id_jabatan) ? $p1->id_jabatan : '';
    $selection_value = '';
    if (isset($_GET['id'])) {
        if ($p1->id_jabatan == $row->pemateri1) {
            $selection_value = "selected";
        } else {
            $selection_value = "";
        }
    }
    $option_title = isset($p1->nama_jabatan) ? $p1->nama_jabatan : '';
    $Selectbox_options .= '<option value="' . $value . '" ' . $selection_value . ' >' . $option_title . '</option>';
}
?>

<li>
    <label>Pemateri 1</label>
    <select name="pemateri1">
           <?php echo $Selectbox_options;?>
    </select>
</li>
<li>
    <label>Pemateri 2</label>
    <select name="pemateri2">
        <?php echo $Selectbox_options;?>
    </select>
</li>
<li>
    <label>Pemateri 3</label>
    <select name="pemateri3">
        <?php echo $Selectbox_options;?>
    </select>
</li>
```

Comment: @Muhammed Khoreiza Q.M.I. is your issue has been fixed or still problem??

Comment: Thank you, i have tried your code, and i get this:
http://i.stack.imgur.com/aANzH.jpg

Comment: at looping line, at Selectbox_options, will value replace with last loop?

Comment: have you checked this variable have values: $jabatan?